# How do I get bars to line up under MusixTeX/BagpipeTeX?

Tags: musixtex

I have one staff spread across four lines, that is, just one instrument.  Each line has four bars.  I want each bar to line up with the one above it.  The MusixTeX documentation refers to bar alignment in Chapter 12, but it seems in the context of multiple instruments and I can't seem to find reference to doing this for my situation.  I'm using BagpipeTeX, which extends MusixTeX to ease typesetting bagpipe music.

Here's a sample that creates what I'm trying to avoid:

```
%&bagpipe
\input bagpipe
%
% HighLad.tex
%
\newpitch\newgrace\noautoglue
%
\ifx\medleyflag\relax\else\nopagenumbers\tall\fi
%
% for line 1
\def\barone{\notes\thrwd\pcps de\etn\grg\pcc fh\enotes\xbarre}
\def\bartwo{\notes\psk\bstst gd4\bgp{\bf\grg}\bep\bd\etn\grg\qlf\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barthree{\notes\dblf\pcc fe\etn\dble\bcss ee3\be\bd\be\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barfour{\notes\dblf\pcc fe\etn\gra\bcss db3{\be\grg}\bd\bb\enotes\alaligne}
%
% for line 2
\def\barfive{\barone}
\def\barsix{\bartwo}
\def\barseven{\notes\thrwd\pcgc d\gre b\etn\dblb\bcss bb3 {\bb\gre}{\ba\grd}\bb\enotes\xbarre}
\def\bareight{\notes\thrwd\pcgc d\gre b\etn\shkb\cb\enotes}
%
% for line 3
\def\barnine{\notes\dblh\bcss hf3\bh\bg\bf\etn\dblg\bcss ge3\bg\bf\be\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barten{\notes\dblf\bcss fd3\bf\be\bd\etn\grg\qlf\enotes\xbarre}
\def\bareleven{\barthree}
\def\bartwelve{\notes\dblf\pcc fe\etn\gra\pcgc e\dblg g\enotes\alaligne}
%
% for line 4
\def\barthirteen{\barnine}
\def\barfourteen{\notes\dblf\bcss fd3\bf\be\bd\etn\grg\bcss ff3{\bf\grg}\be\bf\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barfifteen{\barseven}
\def\barsixteen{\bareight}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
\line{\moyen Highland Laddie\hss
\rm March\hss printed \today\hss BagpipeTEX}
\bigskip
%
\generalmeter{\meterfrac 24}%
%
\debutmorceau
%
\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
% line 1
\leftrepeatsymbol\pickup{\pss ab}%
\barone\bartwo\barthree\barfour
% line 2
\autolines{11}{4}{13}%
\barfive\barsix\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
% line 3
\line{\twelvebf Part 2\hss}
\repreppickup{\dblg\cg}%
\barnine\barten\bareleven\bartwelve
% line 4
\barthirteen\barfourteen\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
%
\byemedley
\bye
```

[image: Highland Laddie]

Here is a tune that has no incomplete measures:

```
%&bagpipe
\input bagpipe
%
%%  GrnHills.tex
%
\newpitch\newgrace\noautoglue
%
\ifx\medleyflag\relax\else\nopagenumbers\fi
%
% for line one
\def\barone{\notes\grg\pcps ab\etn\grip\qlc\etn\dblc\pcgc c\gre a\enotes\xbarre}
\def\bartwo{\notes\grg\pcgc c\thrwd d\etn\dble\qle\etn\gra\pcc ef\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barthree{\notes\dblc\pcc cf\etn\dble\pcps ec\etn\grg\qlb\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barfour{\notes\grip\pcc bf\etn\dble\pcps ec\etn\grN\qla\enotes\alaligne}
% for line two
\def\barfive{\barone}
\def\barsix{\bartwo}
\def\barseven{\barthree}
\def\bareight{\notes\dblb\pcgc b\grN a\etn\dblc\pcps cb\etn\grN\qla\enotes}
% for line three
\def\barnine{\notes\dblc\pcc ce\etn\dblh\qlh\etn\grg\qlh\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barten{\notes\grf\pcc gf\etn\dblf\pcc fe\etn\gra\qle\enotes\xbarre}
\def\bareleven{\notes\grg\pcps ef\etn\dble\pcc ed\etn\shkd\qld\enotes\xbarre}
\def\bartwelve{\notes\grg\pcps de\etn\dbld\pcc dc\etn\grip\qlc\enotes\alaligne}
% for line four
\def\barthirteen{\barnine}
\def\barfourteen{\barten}
\def\barfifteen{\notes\grg\pcps ef\etn\dble\qle\etn\gra\pcps ed\enotes\xbarre}
\def\barsixteen{\notes\grg\pcgc c\thrwd d\etn\dble\he\enotes}
%
\line{\moyen The Green Hills of Tyrol\hss
\rm Retreat March\hss revised \today\hss BagpipeTEX}
\bigskip
%
\generalmeter{\meterfrac 34}%
%
\debutmorceau
%
\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
%line 1
\leftrepeatsymbol
\barone\bartwo\barthree\barfour
% line 2
\barfive\barsix\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
% line 3
\reprmorceau
\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
\leftrepeatsymbol
\barnine\barten\bareleven\bartwelve
% line 4
\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
\barthirteen\barfourteen\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
%
\byemedley
\bye
```

[image: The Green Hills of Tyrol]

Here's an example of something that's ALMOST what I want.  I found it at http://maucamedus.net/musixtex.html as an example of a multi-part score.
[image: almost]

This will work for me IFF I can:

1. Delete all time signatures but the one at the beginning of the first line.  Though it would be nice if I could have the ability to change time signatures within the piece.
2. Delete that vertical line connecting the left ends of the staves.
3. Ensure that a key signature appears only where I want it, right after the clef on the first line, if I want one to appear at all.  Key signature is often left unwritten when the music is for a non-chromatic instrument.
4. Figure some way to allow for a partial bar at the start or end of a line.

When running "The Green Hills of Tyrol" through `autosp`, the result were no changes to the `\anotes` sequences and no spacing was inserted anywhere.  Below are the contents of the log file that was generated:

```
Processing command:\input bagpipe
Processing command:\newpitch\newgrace\noautoglue
Processing command:\ifx\medleyflag\relax\else\nopagenumbers\fi
Processing command:\def\barone{\anotes\grg\pcps ab\etn\grip\qlc\etn\dblc\pcgc c\gre a\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\bartwo{\anotes\grg\pcgc c\thrwd d\etn\dble\qle\etn\gra\pcc ef\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\barthree{\anotes\dblc\pcc cf\etn\dble\pcps ec\etn\grg\qlb\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\barfour{\anotes\grip\pcc bf\etn\dble\pcps ec\etn\grN\qla\en\alaligne}
Processing command:\def\barfive{\barone}
Processing command:\def\barsix{\bartwo}
Processing command:\def\barseven{\barthree}
Processing command:\def\bareight{\anotes\dblb\pcgc b\grN a\etn\dblc\pcps cb\etn\grN\qla\en}
Processing command:\def\barnine{\anotes\dblc\pcc ce\etn\dblh\qlh\etn\grg\qlh\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\barten{\anotes\grf\pcc gf\etn\dblf\pcc fe\etn\gra\qle\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\bareleven{\anotes\grg\pcps ef\etn\dble\pcc ed\etn\shkd\qld\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\bartwelve{\anotes\grg\pcps de\etn\dbld\pcc dc\etn\grip\qlc\en\alaligne}
Processing command:\def\barthirteen{\barnine}
Processing command:\def\barfourteen{\barten}
Processing command:\def\barfifteen{\anotes\grg\pcps ef\etn\dble\qle\etn\gra\pcps ed\en\xbarre}
Processing command:\def\barsixteen{\anotes\grg\pcgc c\thrwd d\etn\dble\he\en}
Processing command:\line{\moyen The Green Hills of Tyrol\hss
Processing command:\rm Retreat March\hss revised \today\hss BagpipeTEX}
Processing command:\bigskip
Processing command:\generalmeter{\meterfrac 34}%
Processing command:\debutmorceau
Processing command:\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
Processing command:\leftrepeatsymbol%
After \bar processing, *ln=%
Processing command:\barone\bartwo\barthree\barfour%
After \bar processing, *ln=\bartwo\barthree\barfour%
Processing command:\bartwo\barthree\barfour%
After \bar processing, *ln=\barthree\barfour%
Processing command:\barthree\barfour%
After \bar processing, *ln=\barfour%
Processing command:\barfour%
After \bar processing, *ln=%
Processing command:\barfive\barsix\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\barsix\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\barsix\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\barseven\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\bareight\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\reprmorceau
Processing command:\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
Processing command:\leftrepeatsymbol%
After \bar processing, *ln=%
Processing command:\barnine\barten\bareleven\bartwelve%
After \bar processing, *ln=\barten\bareleven\bartwelve%
Processing command:\barten\bareleven\bartwelve%
After \bar processing, *ln=\bareleven\bartwelve%
Processing command:\bareleven\bartwelve%
After \bar processing, *ln=\bartwelve%
Processing command:\bartwelve%
After \bar processing, *ln=%
Processing command:\autolines{12}{4}{13}%
Processing command:\barthirteen\barfourteen\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\barfourteen\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\barfourteen\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\barfifteen\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\barsixteen\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
After \bar processing, *ln=\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\setrightrepeat\suspmorceau
Processing command:\byemedley
Processing command:\bye
```

Comment: can you make a sample of your code?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you cannot do what you intend except by doing very manually, because you start with an incomplete bar in the first line, and with a complete bar in the second line. As a musician I cannot see any use of aligning bars in lines when it is not for simultaneous sound.
Musixtex has the possibility of `\parindent`. You could indent the first line so that the first bar would approach the position of the end of the first full bar in the second line, but you still will have to deal with the different amount of notes in the bars, so aligning all remains doing it manually with `\scale` or `\qqsk` or things like that (even `\kern` if you want …).

Comment: I have added a tune to my question that lacks the incomplete bar complication.  Can the bars for this one be made to line up or can I declare that each bar must be X units wide?

Comment: Also, in general pipe music is usually written with the bars aligned.  Most typesetting systems besides TeX/BagpipeTeX do this.

Comment: @Frotz Have you tried the autosp package? According to 3.4 of the manual, this should provide automatic relative note spacing. It is not included in TeXShop. Therefore I cannot try it myself at the moment.

Comment: I wasn't previously aware of this and am looking at it now.  Unfortunately I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.  The manual at https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/autosp/doc is in the form of a standard Unix manpage, so I'm not clear what you mean by "3.4".

Comment: @Frotz, sorry for the incompleteness, I meant the manual of MusiXTeX, which mentions the extension.

Comment: @c-peters: Looking at that section, it looks like I signal autosp to do its thing by using \anotes instead of \notes or whatever.  I tried that and got the same file content as I put into it save some % comments at the ends of some lines and a "Generated by autosp" line at the top.  So I thought maybe I should use /en instead of \enotes.  That didn't help.

Comment: I am sorry that I cannot try myself, but what I see is that your writing of the notes is the way bagpipe does. What does happen when you use the ornaments of bagpipe, but the "normal" note writing like "\ql n" or "\ibu0h2\qb0h\tbu0\qb0i"? You could try with two measures to see whether it produces relative spacing, either or not having ornaments included.